# My cart wont increment the quantity number by 1. Says "NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Im following the book *Agile Web Development with Rails 6* and in *Chapter 10: A Smarter Cart*, we are to build a cart that takes in all the items you have in your cart and lumps them together if you have multiples of the same item and display how many of that item you have.

We build a method in the Cart class:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

which yields the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

We have a class that creates the line_items and allows us to add quantity to the LineItems:

```
class AddQuantityToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 1
  end
end
```

Along with a class to combine the items:

```
class CombineItemsInCart < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    # replace multiple items a single product in a cart with
    # a single item
    Cart.all.each do |cart|
      #count products in the cart
      sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
      sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
        if quantity > 1
          # remove individual items
          cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all

          # replace with a single item
          item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
          item.quantity = quantity
          item.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    LineItem.where("quantity>1").each do |line_item|
      line_item.quantity.times do
        LineItem.create(
          cart_id: line_item.cart_id,
          product_id: line_item.product_id,
          quantity: 1,
        )
      end
      line_item.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I'm baffled at why my cart cannot take the quantity and add 1 to it, nor would it display on my view, which is just:

```
    <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
        <li> <%= item.quantity %> &times; <%= item.product.title %></li>
    <% end %>
```

Whats the best way to have the quantity of the items show and increment?

Comment: Also I dont recommend you use a migration to handle the logic of updating your database,  use a rake task instead

Comment: `quantity` is probably nil. call `to_i` on it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, you only update `line_item` with quantity greater than 1. Therefore any line items that have quantity equal 1 are still having `quantity` column equal nil.

Change this line

```
if quantity > 1
```

To this

```
if quantity == 1
```

And you should move this part of code into a rake task.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the problem?

```
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
```

The above will return an empty ActiveRecord::Relation object. And this will not be nil.

Try this:

```
LineItem.where(id: 1231231231293214082340).nil? # => false
```

Unless you have an existing record in there with that ID, it should return false. What you really want is something like this:

```
current_items = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id).exists?
```

And then you can proceed in your if statement, given those items do exist.

Please note that you will be returning line_items **plural**: you might want to iterate through them, or select your first one.

### Final Code:

```
def add_product(product)
    current_items = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
    if current_items.exists?
      current_item = current_items.first
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

My earlier comment was incorrect: [`find_by` simply uses `where` under the covers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b738f1930f3c82f51741ef7241c1fee691d7deb2/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L80) - they are both the same thing.

### If you have further problems

Then as Josh Brody suggested, quantity might be nil. You might have to update all the quantity items in your database to: 0. Perhaps you could do this with in the migration, given that database is very small.